# Bash Script to copy latest file and send the output to mailid

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**REQUIREMENTS:**

1. Script to check if *.idx file is present in both /a/b/DROP and /a/b/ARCHIVE directories for current date.(DONE)
2. If *.idx file is missing for /a/b/DROP then copy *.idx file from /a/b/ARCHIVE for current date.(only 1 files comes for a day)
3. Need to send the output of the script to few mail id's.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Checking DROP ZIP file for current date
   #***************************************
   filestr=`find /a/b/DROP -name "*.idx" -mtime -1 -print`
         if [ "$filestr" = "" ]; then
           echo "DROP ZIP File missing for `date +%D`"
         else
           echo "DROP ZIP file exists for `date +%D`"
         fi
   #Checking ARCHIVE IDX file for current date
   #******************************************
   filestr=`find /a/b/ARCHIVE -name "*.idx" -mtime -1 -print`
     if [ "$filestr" = "" ]; then
       echo "ARCHIVE IDX File missing for `date +%D`"
     else
       echo "ARCHIVE IDX file exists for `date +%D`"
     fi
   ```

Can someone help me in acheiving the 2nd 3rd requirements?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# req.sh
filestr=`find /a/b/DROP -name "*.idx" -mtime -1 -print`
if [ "$filestr" = "" ]; then
  missing="1"
  echo "DROP ZIP File missing for `date +%D`"
else
  echo "DROP ZIP file exists for `date +%D`"
fi
filestr=`find /a/b/ARCHIVE -name "*.idx" -mtime -1 -print`
if [ "$filestr" = "" ]; then
  echo "ARCHIVE IDX File missing for `date +%D`"
elif [ "$missing" = "1" ];then
  echo "Copying from ARCHIVE `date +%D`"
  cp $filestr /a/b/DROP
else
  echo "ARCHIVE IDX file exists for `date +%D`"
fi
```

Run the script as

```
sh req.sh |/usr/sbin/sendmail -r sender@domain.tld recipient1@domain.tld
```